# ORACLE Query Get Last ID Using MIN Based On Quantity Consumed By ID

Tags: oracle

I have Incoming Stock transaction data using Oracle:

```
ID   | DESCRIPTION | PART_NO | QUANTITY | DATEADDED
TR5  | FG          | P0025   | 5        | 06-SEP-2017 08:20:33 <-- just now added

TR4  | Test        | TEST1   | 8        | 05-SEP-2017 15:11:15
TR3  | FG          | GSDFGSG | 10       | 31-AUG-2017 16:26:04
TR2  | FG          | GSDFGSG | 2        | 31-AUG-2017 16:05:39
TR1  | FG          | GSDFGSG | 2        | 30-AUG-2017 16:30:16
```

And now I'm grouping that data to be:

```
TR_ID | PART_NO | TOTAL
TR1   | GSDFGSG | 14
TR4   | TEST1   | 8
TR5   | P0025   | 5 <-- just now added
```

Query Code:

```
SELECT MIN(TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID) as TR_ID,
PART_NO,
SUM(T.QUANTITY) AS TOTAL
FROM WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT T
GROUP BY T.PART_NO
```

As you can see on that data and query code, I'm show TR_ID using `MIN` to get first ID on first transaction.

And now I have Outgoing transaction data:

Assume I try to get quantity 8

```
ID_FK | QUANTITY
TR1   | 8
```

And now I want to get last ID due to quantity 8 has been consumed

```
ID | DESCRIPTION | PART_NO | QUANTITY
TR3| FG          | GSDFGSG | 10  <-- CONSUMED 4+2+2, TOTAL 8
TR2| FG          | GSDFGSG | 2   <-- CONSUMED 2+2, TOTAL 4
TR1| FG          | GSDFGSG | 2   <-- CONSUMED 2
```

As you can see above, TR1, TR2 has been consumed. Now I want the query

```
SELECT MIN(TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID) as TR_ID,
PART_NO,
SUM(T.QUANTITY) AS TOTAL
FROM WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT T
GROUP BY T.PART_NO
```

get the last id is : TR3, due to TR1 & TR2 has been consumed.

How to do that in query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take minimum `id` where growing sum is greater than 8. Use analytic [`sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm):

```
select min(id) id
  from (select t.*,               
               sum(quantity) over (partition by part_no order by id) sq
          from t
          where part_no = 'GSDFGSG' 
          ) 
  where sq >= 8
```

Test data, output:

```
create table t(ID varchar2(3), DESCRIPTION varchar2(5), 
    PART_NO varchar2(8), QUANTITY number(5), DATEADDED date);

insert into t values ('TR4', 'Test', 'TEST1',    8, timestamp '2017-09-05 15:11:15');
insert into t values ('TR3', 'FG',   'GSDFGSG', 10, timestamp '2017-08-31 16:26:04');
insert into t values ('TR2', 'FG',   'GSDFGSG',  2, timestamp '2017-08-31 16:05:39');
insert into t values ('TR1', 'FG',   'GSDFGSG',  2, timestamp '2017-08-30 16:30:16');
insert into t values ('TR5', 'FG',   'GSDFGSG',  3, timestamp '2017-08-31 17:00:00');
```

Edit:

Add `part_no` and `total` columns and `group by` clause:

```
select min(id) id, part_no, min(sq) total
  from (select t.*,               
               sum(quantity) over (partition by part_no order by id) sq
          from t
          where part_no = 'GSDFGSG' 
          ) 
  where sq >= 8 
  group by part_no


ID  PART_NO       TOTAL
--- -------- ----------
TR3 GSDFGSG          14
```

Comment: Tried your code, worked but PART_NO and TOTAL column not show. TR_ID | PART_NO | TOTAL

Comment: Add these columns as selected values and add `group by`.

Comment: Hi Ponder, thanks for your code. Now I have another question but still in this track. Please see my updated post. How about if I have different PART_NO same description. What I want in query is show all the data, not specific based on PART_NO = 'GSDFGSG'. And sq >= 8 <-- get it from table outgoing (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM WA_II_TBL_TR_OUT_EQUIPMENT)

Comment: Please update your question, add desired output. The main part of the answer remains the same, an analytical sum. We only need to add the appropriate joins and conditions. Now your modified question is unclear for me.

Comment: Hi Ponder, Good day. Let's see my new post regarding this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087528/oracle-query-get-first-transaction-id-based-on-outgoing-transaction-consumed