# Oracle query to get first transaction ID based on outgoing transaction consumed

Tags: oracle

I have Incoming Table Transaction

Table Name: `WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT`

```
TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID | DESCRIPTION | SUPPLIERID_FK | PART_NO | QUANTITY
TE201708000002          | fg          | 62551         | GSDFGSG | 2
TE201709000003          | fg          | 62551         | PA000535| 7
TE201709000002          | fg          | 62551         | GSDFGSG | 9
TE201708000004          | fg          | 62551         | GSDFGSG | 10
TE201708000003          | fg          | 62551         | GSDFGSG | 2
TE201709000001          | Test        | 48544         | Test    | 8
```

On above table we can see 3 `PART_NO`

And now I need to get first `TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID` and grouping to get `SUM(QUANTITY)` based on `PART_NO` to be like:

```
TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID | PART_NO | QUANTITY
TE201708000002          | GSDFGSG | 23
TE201709000003          | PA000535| 7
TE201709000001          | Test    | 8
```

Query:

```
SELECT
   MIN(TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID),
   PART_NO,
   SUM(T.QUANTITY) AS TOTAL
FROM
   WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT T
WHERE
   T.SUPPLIERID_FK = '62551'
GROUP BY
   T.PART_NO
```

As you can see now I can get first `TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID`, that's `TE201708000002`

And now I have Outgoing Table Transaction

Table Name: `WA_II_TBL_TR_OUT_EQUIPMENT`

```
TRANSACTION_OUT_EQUIPMENTID | TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID_FK | QUANTITY <--QUANTITY OUT
TOE201709000001             | TE201708000002             | 3
```

Assume I have outgoing transaction for `PART_NO` = `GSDFGSG` with Quantity Out = 3. (First ID: `TE201708000002` has been inserted.)

And now I want when Querying to get first `TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID` on table `WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT` based on table `WA_II_TBL_TR_OUT_EQUIPMENT`.

`TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID` TE201708000002 has been consumed with quantity out 3. Now it should be get next `TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID` TE201708000003 because it still have quantity rest 1 for these ID.

How to get first `TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID` based on `WA_II_TBL_TR_OUT_EQUIPMENT` consumed?

In this case should be like this:

```
TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID | PART_NO | QUANTITY
TE201708000003          | GSDFGSG | 20 (Rest Quantity, before 23)
TE201709000003          | PA000535| 7
```

### New case below

On table `WA_II_TBL_TR_OUT_EQUIPMENT`, I have this below data:

```
TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID_FK | QUANTITY
TE201708000002             | 3
TE201708000003             | 1
```

When I'm query the code

```
ID             | PART_NO | SEI_NO   | REST
TE201708000003 | GSDFGSG | SDGDFGSD | 1 <-- it should be 0
```

query:

```
select id, part_no, sei_no, sq2 - nvl(oq2, 0) rest
from (
select tr.*, row_number() over (partition by part_no, sei_no order by id) rnk
  from (select i.transaction_equipmentid id, part_no, sei_no, i.quantity iq, 
               sum(i.quantity) over (partition by part_no,sei_no
                                         order by i.transaction_equipmentid) sq1,
               sum(i.quantity) over (partition by part_no, sei_no) sq2,
               o.quantity oq1,
               max(o.quantity) over (partition by part_no, sei_no) oq2
               from wa_ii_tbl_tr_equipment  i 
          left join wa_ii_tbl_tr_out_equipment o 
            on o.transaction_equipmentid_fk = i.transaction_equipmentid
          where i.supplierid_fk = 62551 ) tr
  where sq1 >= oq2 or oq2 is null )
 where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: You might have more luck getting an answer if you could simplify this a bit - it makes my head swim and I give up!  For a start, we don't care that your equipment IDS are like `TE201708000003` - `E1`, `E2` and `E3` would be fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, part_no, sq2-oq2 rest
  from (
    select tr.*, row_number() over (partition by part_no order by id) rnk
      from (select i.transaction_equipmentid id, part_no, i.quantity iq, 
                   sum(i.quantity) over (partition by part_no 
                                             order by i.transaction_equipmentid) sq1,
                   sum(i.quantity) over (partition by part_no) sq2,
                   o.quantity oq1,
                   max(o.quantity) over (partition by part_no) oq2
                   from wa_ii_tbl_tr_equipment  i 
              left join wa_ii_tbl_tr_out_equipment o 
                on o.transaction_equipmentid_fk = i.transaction_equipmentid
              where i.supplierid_fk = 62551 ) tr
      where sq1 >= oq2 or oq2 is null )
  where rnk = 1
```

I join input and output, then using analytic functions `sum()` and `max()` I prepare all needed informations, most important is cumulative sum. You can see it running the most inner query separately, this aliased as `tr`.

Next step is only add `row_number()` to find first row(s) where input is greater than output and show this row and remaining difference.

This condition: `or oq2 is null` is needed to show also other parts (here `PA000535`).

Please read about analytic functions, there are many tutorials on the net.

Test data:

```
create table WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT(
    TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID varchar2(15), DESCRIPTION varchar2(10), 
    SUPPLIERID_FK number(6), PART_NO varchar2(10), QUANTITY number(6));

insert into WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT values ('TE201708000002', 'fg',   62551, 'GSDFGSG',  2);
insert into WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT values ('TE201709000003', 'fg',   62551, 'PA000535', 7);
insert into WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT values ('TE201709000002', 'fg',   62551, 'GSDFGSG',  9);
insert into WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT values ('TE201708000004', 'fg',   62551, 'GSDFGSG', 10);
insert into WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT values ('TE201708000003', 'fg',   62551, 'GSDFGSG',  2);
insert into WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT values ('TE201709000001', 'Test', 48544, 'Test',     8);

create table WA_II_TBL_TR_OUT_EQUIPMENT(
    TRANSACTION_OUT_EQUIPMENTID varchar2(15), 
    TRANSACTION_EQUIPMENTID_FK varchar2(15), 
    QUANTITY number(6));

insert into WA_II_TBL_TR_OUT_EQUIPMENT values('TOE201709000001', 'TE201708000002', 3);
```

Output:

```
ID              PART_NO          REST
--------------- ---------- ----------
TE201708000003  GSDFGSG            20
TE201709000003  PA000535
```

Comment: Awesome Sir, worked as well. Cheers. Thank you very much Ponder

Comment: Hi Ponder, question: how about to get REST, SUM(QUANTITY) FROM incoming - SUM(QUANTITY) FROM outgoing? I tried to empty the table WA_II_TBL_TR_OUT_EQUIPMENT, when query it the result is empty

Comment: In that case instead of `sq2 - oq2` use `sq2 - nvl(oq2, 0)`.

Comment: Worked perfect Sir. Case closed. Thanks Ponder

Comment: Hi Ponder, I just updated my question above, please have a look there.

Comment: Looks like You want to sum all output quantities at first. So use `sum()` instead of `max()` to calculate value `oq2`. This worked for me.

Comment: Yes, now the query is correct. And question again Ponder, if the REST quantity is 0, I wouldn't show it, is it possible? Only if rest quantity is 0

Comment: You can use [`nullif()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm) function or `case when ...`. For instance: `nullif(sq2 - nvl(oq2, 0), 0)`.

Comment: Hi Ponder, how about if to hide the row, I set REST >= 0, but I don't know where I have to put. Please help

Comment: Hi Ponder, I have another issue, when try to consume quantity with same ID twice, sum query is not correct it's not reduce the quantity but increase the quantity.

Comment: Hi Ponder, really need your help. Please have a look on this fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2da39/3/0 the rest of this ID: TE201709000003 should be 7 not 12.

Comment: Hi. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2da39/5). From what I see Transaction ID in output data repeats. So you have to group output data at first and then make join.Sorry for delayed answers, I'm busy lately.